# Why do my Nine Patch images not work when compiled?

Tags: java, android, xml, nine-patch

I'm attempting to create customs buttons using icons instead of text, and this requires the background property of each button view to utilise a nine patch image, where everything bar the icon can be scaled.

When I select my nine patch image, the WYSIWYG editor displays it as it should (https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdXM5.png) but when compiled to either the emulator or a device, the image is scaled like a normal .png but with the nine patch lines visible (https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEOGn.png)

I have performed multiple clean & rebuilds, as well as moving the swinglabs jar into the lib folder of the tools directory, but still it doesn't seem to work. I'd be happy to provide any other information you may need to answer this question, the things become the bane of this app!

---

My images were created through the draw9patch tool and saved with the .9.png postfix via the tool

---

Thanks Guys! It was my mistake in not quite understanding the nine patch scale/fill relationships in the top/left and bottom/right 1px lines, thanks again!
    - Ciaren Coleman

Comment: Use the tool provided by sdk draw9patch. sdk-path/tools/draw9patch. There you will be able to see the result.

Comment: How are you setting the drawable? XML or code? Can you upload the image so we can check it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]the top line is missing in your nine patch that is  where the problem lies there should be some pixels on the top to tell what to stretch like u have done in the left side. Whithout top and left lines nine patch is not complete.

Chech the link [enter link description here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html)

Comment: Hi Ravi, I used the draw9patch tool to create my images, and save them as .9.png via the tool. I first saved them in the drawable-hdpi folder, and then tried the drawable-xhdpi folder; both didn't work.

Comment: i found your problem . the lower line and the right line is used to define where the content should lie of the view like if u put text on the button but top and left lines define what area should be stretched

Comment: it should be like this for what u wanna achieve . In short you have to mark some pixels on top to define horizontal scaling which is missing in ur image

Answer (score 0):

Image name should look like

```
xxx.9.png
```

Only then android knows that this is nine path image

Comment: My images are given that notation when saved through the draw_nine_patch tool (http://i.imgur.com/RcxVJPY.png) but are not referenced as such in the xml document, should this be changed?

Comment: Is dog_nine_path.9.png and dogbuttonimg_hd9 same file? Shouldn't you use @drawable/dog_nine_path?

Comment: Ah sorry, my mistake, that was a misalignment when taking the screenshot, I am using a different nine patch image with the name dogbuttonimg_hd9, the correct screenshot is here (http://i.imgur.com/h3HB59w.png)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

please check this image to put in your code.
and simple image is made in 9patch.again check this image

Comment: we can not create image with icon.because it will always stretch.

Comment: thats the reason we have nine patch images to define the parts we wanna scale and only those parts are scaled. Check the link and image in the above answer

Comment: This is my final configuration which works on both the device and the editor, thanks guys. http://i.imgur.com/lDnwqEX.png

Comment: just to clarify the lines at the bottom and the right define the content area like for text in button. Since u r using a image as background of the buttom you dont necessarily have to draw the lines only for the part where icon is u can draw them for whole bottom and right part , to understand this better put some text with android:text attribute with your current image you will get my point   and moreover one pixel is more than enough to provide the scaling if its a solid color